# Spring boot runtime error details

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-annotations, spring-java-config

I'm a beginner to spring and spring boot.I'm using command line runner to execute my application.I was facing issue that my application services stops immediately without any error when I run the application. After reviewing all files i came to know that one of autowired variable was not having @component notation in its class.After fixing it started working fine.

My question here is, is there a run time debugger in spring boot to trace these types of errors ?

Comment: sorry i'm not sure about the answer for your question but i suggest you try **Spring Tool Suite** https://spring.io/tools/sts it will help more with spring.

Answer (score 1):

1. inside `src/main/resources/application.properties` or `src/main/resources/application.yml` add

   ```
   debug: true
   ```
2. run with debug using spring-boot property

   ```
   java -jar /path/to/file.jar --debug
   ```
3. run with debug using jvm args

   ```
   java -Ddebug -jar /path/to/file.jar
   ```
4. also you can ise IDE such Itellij IDEA (in Run Configurations) for your main class
   [image: check enable debug output in Spring Boot Settings]

ps: I believe, other IDEs, such as eclipse / STS or NetBeans also should have similar property

5. set env variable DEBUG=true and run app

   5.1. unix bash: `DEBUG=true java -jar /path/to/file.jar`

   5.2. windows cmd:

   ```
      set DEBUG=true
      java -jar path\to\file.jar
   ```